# How do I set a new SVG Path starting point?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path, animation, css

I'm animating an SVG using CSS and I need to edit the SVG to have a new starting point for the animation.

The path is relative.

How can I go about doing this in Inkscape?

[Same issue but Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60341/how-to-change-which-anchor-point-on-a-path-is-the-starting-anchor)

[Same issue but never returned with solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831044/inkscape-how-to-change-starting-node)

Comment: Assuming the SVG uses absolute path commands just cut/paste so that it starts where you need it to

Comment: @Cai unfortunately they are relative

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097242/inkscape-reset-first-node/50194469#50194469